# Getting sub strings separated by pipes given the exact positions of the pipes

Tags: c, substring, text-files, c-strings

I searched through and didn’t get a quite working answer. Although I know that still there might be plenty of answers out there. Honestly I couldn’t find it as I am a beginner to C/C++ .

My problem is I have a text file which has data on it separated by pipes('|'). Actually a log file. In each entry things are separated by pipes('|') and each entry is separated by new line('\n')its really lengthy. So I wanted to do is that when user gives a sequence `sequence=[2,5,7]` the function should be able to read that array and give only the things starting with that pipe position. So here It should give 2nd ,5th, and 7th things in to a text file. down here is the code I used. It doesnt work for some reason I can't find. It gives the resulting text file printed out only with the '\n' and no more.Its more thant the entries in the file too.

`minorSeparatorChar` is the charactor given as '|'

`majorSeparatorChar` is the charactor given as '\n'

`inFile` Input text file

`outFile` output text file

`minSepCount` minor separator count

`majSepCount` major separator count

`sequence` is a global const int array

```
void getFormattedOutput(char * inFile, char * outFile, char minorSeparatorChar,char majorSeparatorChar){

FILE *readFile,*writeFile;
int charactor=0, minSepCount=0, i=0,majSepCount = 0;
int flagMin = 0;
char charactorBefore = NULL;
readFile = fopen(inFile,"r");       // opens the file for reading
writeFile = fopen(outFile,"w");     // opens the file for writing

if (readFile==NULL || writeFile == NULL){
    printf("\nFile creation is not a sucess, Exiting program..\n");
    exit(0);
    }


while(charactor!=EOF){

    charactorBefore = charactor;
    if (charactor==minorSeparatorChar)
        flagMin=1;
    charactor = fgetc(readFile);
    if(charactorBefore == minorSeparatorChar){
        flagMin = 0;
        if (minSepCount==sequence[i]){
            fputc(charactor,writeFile);

            continue;
            }
        i++;

        minSepCount++;
    }

    else if (charactorBefore == majorSeparatorChar){
        minSepCount=0;
        i=0;
        majSepCount++;
        fputc('\n',writeFile);
        }       

    else{
        if(flagMin==1)
            fputc(charactor,writeFile);
        continue;
    }

}       

fclose(readFile);
fclose(writeFile);

}
```

for example if the input file has

```
33|333|67|787|7889|9876554|56
20151001|0|0|0|0||94|71
1|94|71|1|94|71|1
```

and if I give sequence `[2,5,6]`

It should print to out file as

```
67  9876554 56
 0       94 71
71       71  1
```

Comment: Please describe the behaviour of your program in more detail. "It doesn't work" rarely conveys any meaningful information. In particular, please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then provide sample input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: Where is sequence defined? I can't see it.  Do you really have a global variable that you check against before printing the characters out (except for the newline) so that must be where the problem is and you don't even let us see what is in that variable?

Comment: yes the global variable is the sequence [] array.

Comment: Is field 5 in the second row an empty string or the number 94? In other words, are several consecutive separators treated as a single separator?

Comment: its 94. no two consecative separators trated as 2. where it should print nothing and ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately concluded that there were too many flags and controls and variables in your code and that I couldn't make head or tail of what they were up to, and decided to rewrite the code.  I couldn't see in your code how you knew how many fields were in the sequence, for example.

I write in C11 (C99), but in this program, that simply means that I declare variables when they're needed, not at the top of the function.  If it's a problem (C89/C90), move the declarations to the top of the function.

I also find that the names used were so long that they obscured the purpose of the variables.  You may think I've gone too far in the other direction; more significantly, your professor (teacher) may think that.  So be it; names are fungible and global search and replace works well.

I also don't see how your code is supposed to interpolate semi-arbitrary numbers of blanks between the fields, so I've actually ducked the issue.  This code outputs the field separator (`minor_sep` — a length reduction of `minorSeparatorChar`) and the record separator (`major_sep` — reduced from `majorSeparatorChar`) at the appropriate points.

I note that field numbers start with field 0 in your code.  I'm not convinced your code would ever output data from field 0, but that is somewhat tangential given the rewrite.

I ended up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static const int sequence[] = { 2, 5, 7 };
static const int seqlen = 3;

static
void getFormattedOutput(char *inFile, char *outFile, char minor_sep, char major_sep)
{
    FILE *ifp = fopen(inFile, "r");  // opens the file for reading
    FILE *ofp = fopen(outFile, "w"); // opens the file for writing

    if (ifp == NULL || ofp == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nFile creation is not a success, Exiting program..\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    int c;
    int seqnum = 0;
    int fieldnum = 0;
    while ((c = getc(ifp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == major_sep)
        {
            putc(major_sep, ofp);
            fieldnum = 0;
            seqnum = 0;
        }
        else if (c == minor_sep)
        {
            if (seqnum < seqlen && fieldnum == sequence[seqnum])
            {
                putc(minor_sep, ofp);
                seqnum++;
            }
            fieldnum++;
        }
        else if (fieldnum == sequence[seqnum])
            fputc(c, ofp);
    }

    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);
}

int main(void)
{
    getFormattedOutput("/dev/stdin", "/dev/stdout", '|', '\n');
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it (I called it `split`, though it isn't a good choice since there is also a standard command `split`), I get:

```
$ echo "fld0|fld1|fld2|fld3|fld4|fld5|fld6|fld7|fld8|fld9" | ./split 
fld2|fld5|fld7|
$ echo "fld0|fld1|fld2|fld3|fld4|fld5|fld6" | ./split 
fld2|fld5|
$
```

The only possible objection is that there is a field terminator rather than a field separator.  As you can see, a terminator is not hard to implement; making it into a separator (so there isn't a pipe after the last field on the line, even when the line doesn't have as many fields as there are elements in the sequence — see the second sample output) is trickier.  The code needs to output a separator when it reads the first character of a field that should be printed after the first such field.  This code achieves that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static const int sequence[] = { 2, 5, 7 };
static const int seqlen = 3;

static
void getFormattedOutput(char *inFile, char *outFile, char minor_sep, char major_sep)
{
    FILE *ifp = fopen(inFile, "r");  // opens the file for reading
    FILE *ofp = fopen(outFile, "w"); // opens the file for writing

    if (ifp == NULL || ofp == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nFile creation is not a success, Exiting program..\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    int c;
    int seqnum = 0;
    int fieldnum = 0;
    int sep = 0;
    while ((c = getc(ifp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == major_sep)
        {
            putc(major_sep, ofp);
            fieldnum = 0;
            seqnum = 0;
            sep = 0;
        }
        else if (c == minor_sep)
        {
            if (seqnum < seqlen && fieldnum == sequence[seqnum])
                seqnum++;
            fieldnum++;
            sep = minor_sep;
        }
        else if (fieldnum == sequence[seqnum])
        {
            if (sep != 0)
            {
                putc(sep, ofp);
                sep = 0;
            }
            putc(c, ofp);
        }
    }

    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);
}

int main(void)
{
    getFormattedOutput("/dev/stdin", "/dev/stdout", '|', '\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Example run:

```
$ {
> echo "Afld0|Afld1|Afld2|Afld3|Afld4|Afld5|Afld6|Afld7|Afld8|Afld9"
> echo "Bfld0|Bfld1|Bfld2|Bfld3|Bfld4|Bfld5|Bfld6|Bfld7|Bfld8|Bfld9"
> echo "Cfld0|Cfld1|Cfld2|Cfld3|Cfld4|Cfld5|Cfld6|Cfld7|Cfld8|Cfld9"
> echo "Dfld0|Dfld1|Dfld2|Dfld3|Dfld4|Dfld5|Dfld6|Dfld7|Dfld8|Dfld9"
> echo "Efld0|Efld1|Efld2|Efld3|Efld4|Efld5|Efld6|Efld7|Efld8|Efld9"
> } | ./split
|Afld2|Afld5|Afld7
|Bfld2|Bfld5|Bfld7
|Cfld2|Cfld5|Cfld7
|Dfld2|Dfld5|Dfld7
|Efld2|Efld5|Efld7
$
```